# React : Accessing props data through NavLink from parent component

Tags: reactjs

I want to send integer value using NavLink from parent component and access the same in Child component
For example if I pass integer 1 from parent component (i.e. from head component)
so i can use the same in my child component.
Below is the code snippet

```
<button className='rounded-corner-btn'>Comics<br/><NavLink to= 
{`/head/${1}`} ></NavLink></button>
```

The url `/head/${1}` this integer i want to use in my child component to render another component

Answer (score 2):

If you define your child route like

```
<Route path="/head/:id" component={Child}/>
```

you can access the id in which is an integer in child like

`this.props.match.params.id` if you are using react-router-v4 or above and then take necessary actions

Comment: Still not able to acess

Comment: getting an undefined value

Comment: Can you show your component, also are you using react-router-v4

Comment: Yes i m using react router v4